# How to print ring type output in c?

Tags: c

I have c program problem to print the ring type output.

**When user enter the number 5, then program output is look like;**

```
1     2      3     4    5
16    17    18    19    6
15    24    25    20    7
14    23    22    21    8
13    12    11    10    9
```

I use following logic but i really failed i not have any idea.

```
 int main()
    {
        int a[50],i,j=0,n,k;
        printf("Enter the number=");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {

            if(i>n)
            {
                j=j+5;
            }
            else if(i>((2*n)-1))
            {
                j--;
            }
            else if(i>((3*n)-2))
            {
                j=j-5;
            }
            else if(i>(4*n-4))
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry for asking whole program logic but
,I really dont have any idea,Please help me.....

Comment: how could this `if(i>n)` become true?

Comment: sorry but i not have any idea for this program

Comment: Maybe "spiral" would be the better word than "ring" to help people understand what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what you are looking for

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max 25

int main()
{
    int spiral[max][max] = {{0}}; // initializing array with 0
    int r, c, i = 0, j = -1, count = 1;

    printf("\nEnter the row and column for spiral matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r, &c);

    while (count <= r * c)  // this loop executes till all the blocks of
    {
        // array r*c are filled with 0
        while (j < c - 1) // Filling the location from left to right
        {
            // with value of variable count
            if(spiral[i][j+1]!=0)  // Here we are checking if that location
                break;                 // is already occupied
            spiral[i][++j] = count++;
        }

        while (i < r - 1)    // Filling the location from top to bottom
        {
            if (spiral[i+1][j] != 0)
                break;
            spiral[++i][j] = count++;
        }

        while (j > 0)     // Filling the location from right to left
        {
            if(spiral[i][j-1] != 0)
                break;
            spiral[i][--j] = count++;
        }

        while (i > 0)       // Filling the column from bottom to top
        {
            if (spiral[i-1][j] != 0)
                break;
            spiral[--i][j] = count++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < r ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < c ; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d",spiral[i][j]); // print the matrix
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

reference is [here from more details](http://www.programmingspark.com/2012/10/c-program-to-print-spiral-pattern.html)

Comment: Don't do people's homework.  Teach them to find the answers themselves.  Also get rid of the `#include <conio.h>`, do not use tabs, check user input values are really between 1 and max.

Comment: @chqrlie relax any ways thanx for advice

Comment: the final printf format is incorrect: it should read `" %3d"` for the numbers to appear separate, and `"%-5d "` with extra logic for the last column if you want to match the actual output in the OP's question.

Comment: If you are not going to give good answers then don't complin, 1.Your code was so badly formatted that I was crying until I fixed it, 2. Your code contains errors as pointed out by @chqrlie, 3. You did the OP's homework, you sure had fun, so for me that's ok, but you did it wrong.

Comment: @BhargavModi that's your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this problem is to allocate an array of size N*N and to populate it with a straight forward loop that follows the spiral.  Then you can print the array contents N elements per row.

Comment: Try and write your own code for this assignment and look at the related link if you fail.  The real achievement would be to write code that does this without allocation, and in O(n) time.

Comment: sorry chqrlie, for asking whole program